# SPFX Webpart width shrinked after published in Modern Page - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, office-ui-fabric-react

Developing SPFX app, where everything looks good(I mean the width) in edit mode, soon after publish the webpart width is getting reduced somehow.

Using Fabric UI CSS

```
.propertyDigitalManagementWebpart {
  .container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .grid {
    @include ms-Grid;
  }

  .row {
    @include ms-Grid-row;
    //@include ms-fontColor-white;
    //background-color: $ms-color-themeDark;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .column10 {
    @include ms-Grid-col;
    @include ms-lg10;
    @include ms-xl8;
  }

  .column2 {
    @include ms-Grid-col;
    @include ms-lg2;
  }

  .column1 {
    @include ms-Grid-col;
    @include ms-lg1;
  }
```

Main webpart has below code

```
<div className={styles.propertyDigitalManagementWebpart}>
        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <ContainerComponent />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Sub Component - Container

```
 <div className={styles.row}>
        <div className={selectedPrptyRecord ? styles.column9 : styles.column12} >
          <TextField id="standard-basic" label="Search" onChange={srcTextFieldChange} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <div className={selectedPrptyRecord ? styles.column9 : styles.column12} >
          <div style={{ minHeight: "768px" }} >
            <DataGrid rows={propertyRecords} columns={columns} pageSize={10}
              onSelectionChange={(newSelection) => {
                console.log("selection event");
                console.dir(newSelection);
                SelectedRowEvent(newSelection.rowIds);
              }}
              hideFooterSelectedRowCount={true}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {selectedPrptyRecord != null && Object.keys(selectedPrptyRecord).length > 0 &&
          <SidePanelComponent selectedRecord={selectedPrptyRecord} closeEvent={handleClose} />
        }
      </div>
```

[image]

I don't know what's causing the issue to shrink the webpart after publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the workaround or css tweak is

```
:global(#workbenchPageContent) {  
  max-width: initial;  
} 

:global(.CanvasZone > div) {  
  width: 100%;  
}
```